# Making minimal modification to JSON data without a structure in golang

Tags: json, go, solr

I have a solr response in JSON format which looks like this:

```
 {
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "q": "solo",
      "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 2,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
          <Large nested JSON element>
      },
      {
          <Large nested JSON element>
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, in my Golang app, I would like to quickly remove the "responseHeader" so that I can return the "response" alone. How can I do this without creating large structures?

---

## Edit 1

The answer by evanmcdonnal was the solution to this problem, but it had some minor typos, this is what I ended up using:

```
var temp map[string]interface{}

if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &temp); err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

result, err := json.Marshal(temp["response"])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a really brief example of how to do this quickly and easily. The steps are; unmarshal into the universal `map[string]interface{}` then, assuming no errors, marshal only the inner object which you want.

```
var temp := &map[string]interface{}

if err := json.Unmarshal(input, temp); err != nil {
     return err;
}

return json.Marshal(temp["response"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a package [µjson](https://github.com/olvrng/ujson) to do exactly that: performing generic transformations on JSON documents without unmarshalling them.

[Run on Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RHlqJPeUEkz)

```golang
input := []byte(`
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 0,
    "params": {
      "q": "solo",
      "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 2,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      { "name": "foo" },
      { "name": "bar" }
    ]
  }
}`)

blacklistFields := [][]byte{
    []byte(`"responseHeader"`), // note the quotes
}
b := make([]byte, 0, 1024)
err := ujson.Walk(input, func(_ int, key, value []byte) bool {
    for _, blacklist := range blacklistFields {
        if bytes.Equal(key, blacklist) {
            // remove the key and value from the output
            return false
        }
    }

    // write to output
    if len(b) != 0 && ujson.ShouldAddComma(value, b[len(b)-1]) {
        b = append(b, ',')
    }
    if len(key) > 0 {
        b = append(b, key...)
        b = append(b, ':')
    }
    b = append(b, value...)
    return true
})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%s", b)
// Output: {"response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[{"name":"foo"},{"name":"bar"}]}}
```

You can [read more about it on the blog post](https://olvrng.github.io/w/ujson/). I put the answer here just in case someone else might need it.